# SVG not showing shadow and losing quality

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, svg

I have created the svg below. A frame with small details with some shadowing round it.
[image: Original SVG]

However, when I import it to react-native using react-native-svg, it loses the shadow round the frame and small bits of details.
[image: React-native frame]

I've importing the file itself.

```
import {SvgXml} from 'react-native-svg';
import testSvg from '../../assets/svg/small_frame.svg';
<SvgXml xml={testSvg} />
```

And I've also tried copying and pasting the contents of the svg to a string and using that.

However, both result in the shadow around the frame missing.

If I open up the SVG file on the browser, the shadow appears, so it must be something in react-native I'm missing.

Comment: Your "Original SVG" is a PNG, not a SVG. The StackOverflow editor has a [ < > ] button to include code...

Comment: @Danny'365CSI'Engelman its intended to be a png, just showing what i'm expecting to see. There's nothing wrong with the svg itself, theres a lack of support for filters in react-native. I was hoping for a workaround

Answer (score 1):

react-native-svg doesn't support filters in svg's yet.

It's been extensively tracked here https://github.com/react-native-svg/react-native-svg/issues/150

My workaround was to put the `<SvgXml />` in a view and add a shadow to that view, it works well so far with complex shapes.